# Can a querylocator be used across connections

Tags: soql, soap-api

I want to execute a query which will return huge number of records.

I want to execute it in parallel by running it in separate nodes.

Is it possible to use a single querylocator with many connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to execute a query which will return huge number of records.*

> You can use QueryLocator. It is made for this porpose.

*I want to execute it in parallel by running it in separate nodes.*

> You can run upto 5 QueryLocator. **(But use this limit with caution)**

*Is it possible to use a single querylocator with many connections?*

> No, a single QueryLocator holds result set for single query only. It
>   has offset and pagination references to return rows requested.